# Wifi network keeps disappearing (Intel 3160 wireless card)

Tags: release-loki, wifi

I have a lenovo b50, recently installed elementary os.

While the wifi is theoretically working at times, it keeps fooling around after coming back from sleep mode. What it does is, that it suddenly cannot detect any wifi connections, unless I type my network name into "find hidden network".

output of  sudo lshw -C network
 is:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:76:1c:1f:6c:25
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2604000-c2604fff memory:c2600000-c2603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 93
       serial: d0:7e:35:2d:40:bf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=10.0.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:52 memory:c2500000-c2501fff
```

Comment: What's the output of "sudo lshw -C network"?

Comment: i added it to the op

Comment: What is the output for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Intel 3160 driver. You can install a forked driver to prevent power saving error after coming up from sleep mode.

I have installed it on my Lenovo G50-80 with the same wifi card. Download and untar the new driver from:

[Bitseater's dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6u99l59k47qwcu/lenovo-wifi-fix.tar.gz?dl=0)

in your home folder. Now open a terminal **into the new folder** and type:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
sudo apt-get install build-essential
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp ideapad-laptop.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf
```

I have added a readme file with the instructions. Reboot and try to connect to your SSID.

**Updated**

To prevent wireless card stop working after coming from sleep mode, open a terminal and type:

```
echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: sudo cp ideapad-laptop.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/ after tis line it states no such file or directory exists.. extracted the drive to home folder

Comment: Ups. My fault. You must install linux-headers to compile the driver. Modifying my answer...

Comment: hmm i tried sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic and sudo apt-get install dkms

mkdir kernel
cd kernel

#Install Kernel 3.12.2 on 64 Bit
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.2-trusty/linux-headers-3.12.2-031202-generic_3.12.2-031202.201311291538_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.2-trusty/linux-headers-3.12.2-031202_3.12.2-031202.201311291538_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.2-trusty/linux-image-3.12.2-031202-generic_3.12.2-031202.201311291538_amd64.deb but still same problem..

Comment: What's your elementary-os version?

Comment: 0.4 Loki (64-bit)

Comment: Do not install linux-3.12. Loki is based on 4.4 version and above. Is there any ideapad-laptop.ko file on your lenovo-wifi-fix folder?

Comment: i see. does it mean I have to remove that again?

Comment: Yes if you have installed them.

Comment: the file is named ideapad-laptop.c

Comment: You must run make as in instructions to build the ideapad-laptop.ko file.

Comment: @user8000 answer edited. I hope it help you

Comment: thanks for trying to help! I noticed I missed your notion to "open terminal into THE NEW FOLDER". got past the make line, but with sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf it now says ad.conf
rm: cannot remove '/etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: Right. This file does not always exist. Reboot and try to connect

Comment: okey unfortunately it happened again, network disapperead after pc coming back from sleep mode

Comment: Try with my update

Comment: still same problem.. could it have something to do with wifi power management?

Comment: Try changing the parameters in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf.  To know the avalaibles parameters try from terminal with modinfo iwlmvm. Also try adding some options to iwlwifi,  with avalaibles parameters from modinfo iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

You can mange options with changing the parameters in /erc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf.  To know the avalaibles parameters try from terminal with **modinfo iwlmvm**. Try too with the parameters of iwlwifi: **modinfo** **iwlwifi**