# WIFI sometimes not working

Tags: release-loki, wifi

I just installed Elementary OS on my Lenovo Yoga.

During install everything worked as expected.

No when I reboot sometimes no networks are found.

To fix this I got to reboot various times.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Are you tried http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10015/565?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi problems after restart or suspend](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/wifi-problems-after-restart-or-suspend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on the wifi adapter and its drivers as suggested by the other answer, or it may be a more broad ubuntu 16.04 buggy thing discussed in this askubuntu question: [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/47206).

The answer that seems to work for me in elementary is this: https://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206.

What it says is:

- Get details of your PCI wireless card by running `sudo lshw -class network`
- Get your card model info according to the product line. For something like `RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`, the model of the card is `RTL8723BE`
- Open or create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`(replace `rtl8723be` with your own model number) Then run `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot.

---

If this doesn't work, one can, as an emergency solution, restart the network manager with `service network-manager restart`. I find it easier to use the command `bash -c 'service network-manager restart'` with a shortcut or launcher.